# mongodb insert into collection with nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, callback

I'm trying to insert into collection but I get error not sure why. here is what I tried to do

```
db.collection("book", function(err, collection){

    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    }

    collection.insert({"name":req.query.file.split(".")[0],"length":response}, function(err,book) {
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }

        return callback(null);
        console.log(book);
    });

    return callback(null);

});
```

I'm trying to insert a "book" into book collection... as I saw in mongo document .collection and .insert requires callback.
and my error is

```
events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: listen EADDRINUSE
    at errnoException (net.js:900:11)
    at Server._listen2 (net.js:1038:14)
    at listen (net.js:1060:10)
    at net.js:1134:9
    at dns.js:72:18
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
```

and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, thanks!

Comment: The "callback" is the argument you have specified as a `function()` in both of your method calls. What is `callback()` that you have put in there twice? Possibly too literal a translation from the documentation or is it intended to be something else?

Comment: well, I throwed the callbacks, I have it like this now: http://pastebin.com/M86GM08B still same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that it is because of insert? It is typical unhandled exception in case you try to start node.js process that listens for the same port as other process( or the same copy of this node.js process)